# Web API 2.0 HttpResponseMessage return type returns HTTP401

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-blob-storage, jwt

```
    [Authorize]
    public string GetBlob(Guid id)
    {

        var blockBlob = _cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(id.ToString());
        blockBlob.FetchAttributes();

        long length = blockBlob.Properties.Length;
        var byteArray = new byte[length];
        blockBlob.DownloadToByteArray(byteArray, 0);
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
        //return response;

        return "Test";
     }
```

The correct JWT token is being passed in the header.  The code above works just fine.  However, if I uncomment "response" (line that's commented out) and change the return type to HttpResponseMessage, it will gives me an HTTP 401 unauthorized error, even though I can hit every other method in this controller (including this one when return type is string) and get an HTTP 200 response.

Any ideas?

I tried to comment out portions of this, and its basically the return type that causes the HTTP 401.  If I return the HttpResponseMessage, I get a 401.  If I leave the rest of the code in tact and just return a string, it works. I am stumped. :(

Comment: What is `_cloudBlobContainer` and has that been set up correctly?

Comment: _cloudBlobContainer was set up in the constructor.  This is part of the Azure Blob storage API for fetching binary objects from Azure Blob storage. Yes, it is set up correctly.  It functions just fine.  No exceptions are thrown, and I am able to properly fetch items in the blob storage by their identifier.

Comment: Yes, but have the storage credentials been set up in your CloudBlobContainer object?